# Why this won't be called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the gem called "auto_html" ( https://github.com/dejan/auto_html )
I did set up this in my user model.
However it seems that it's not replacing with this condition.
It means this is not called when User saves his own profile.
How can I apply this to the actions like update or new?

```
AutoHtml.add_filter(:introduction) do |text|
    text.gsub(/http:\/\/.+\.(jpg|jpeg|bmp|gif|png)(\?\S+)?/i) do |match|
        %|<img src="#{match}" alt="max-width:auto"/>|
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you wrapped this code into a model method that you call in a `before_save` callback?

Comment: @MrYoshiji what do you mean? I did wrap  this code into User model. But did nothing with before_save thing:(

Comment: How can I call this as before_save? I was think this would will work automatically when it saves.

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thanks so much:) I'm looking forward to it

Answer (score 0):

`auto_html_for` is the method that you're looking for.

`add_filter` is for modifying the behavior of `AutoHtml` itself. For plugging this into an individual model, [the documentation](https://github.com/dejan/auto_html#example-usage) has a pretty clear example case.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  auto_html_for :body do
    html_escape
    image
    youtube(:width => 400, :height => 250)
    link :target => "_blank", :rel => "nofollow"
    simple_format
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'd like to use  add_filter only for images because I want to put some tags for additional tag. How can I?